# The car is speeding around the bend

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms

Could the following sentence mean " the car is speeding in a crazy manner/ in high speed / uncontrollable way" or it can have only one meaning?

> The car is speeding around the bend.

Comment: @AlanCarmack oops..sorry I misspelled it.

Comment: Are you confused because of the idiom ["around the bend'](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/round+the+bend) meaning "having lost sanity/gotten very drunk"? Typically we only use that with people - 'Why is Colleen editing all questions tagged grammar? She's gone completely around the bend!"

Comment: @ColleenV yes that was the point made me confused but I think " around " is a preposition here

Comment: I think your question may get more attention if you [edit] your answer to explain why you think (or thought) the sentence might be able to be interpreted in different ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The car is speeding around the bend

only means that the car is going fast (perhaps in excess of the speed limit). The idiomatic usage of "around the bend" (which I think must be more common in BrE than in AmE) to mean "insane" only applies to people ... and maybe animals(?)

This might mean that the car is being driven in a crazy / uncontrollable manner:

> The car is careening around the bend.

Comment: It *might* mean *crazy / uncontrollable* (or, as you say, *in excess of the speed limit*). But the usage could also occur in the context of an F1 racing car driver with very tight control of his vehicle (and no suggestion of exceeding any speed limit), so although I agree your first 9 words above are unassailable, I'm not so sure about substituting ***careening***, since that almost always implies great speed *without* control. And actually, *to speed **out of** a bend* would normally be something done very deliberately, *with* control, since it gives better traction & control of inertia.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  do you agree it has nothing to do with the noun bend which means "a curve or turn, especially in a road or river". http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bend_2

Comment: In the phrase "around the bend", the word **bend** absolutely does refer to the noun.  The car is speeding around the curve.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "careening" was clearly suggested _in the context of_ "crazy / uncontrollable". So... I think you actually just agreed with me.

Comment: @G. Ann: Well, it seems the only reason OP has asked the question is because he's conflating the cited *(literal)* usage with idiomatic [*around the bend*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/around-the-bend) = *​mentally ​confused or ​unable to ​act in a ​reasonable way*, which has ***absolutely nothing to do with his context***. And as is clear from his comment above, OP ***still*** had this mistaken impression ***after*** reading your answer. So even though I don't disagree with anything specific that you said here, it obviously didn't lead to "instant enlightenment" for OP.

Comment: Incidentally, apparently the origin of the idiomatic usage is uncertain. One leading contender is: [The 'bend' is the curve always placed in the entrance drive of Victorian mental hospitals. Straight drives were the characteristic of stately homes and bent ones of asylums to screen the inmates from view and vise versa.](http://askaboutenglish.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/phrase-of-day-154-round-bend.html). Colourful, that! :)

Comment: Ah! I missed those comments @FumbleFingers. It never occurred to me that anyone would think a car was going crazy. :-/

Comment: In light of that, might you consider editing to make the situation absolutely clear? As it happens, my "possible etymology" above *does* reference "bend" as a curve in a road, but it's probably fanciful anyway. Other possibilities are a connection with *bend = type of sailor's knot*, or some relationship with similar terms such as ***loopy, twisted, screwed up***, so there really is no particular reason to think of the idiomatic usage as having any (past ***or*** present) connection to bends in roads that you might drive round in an unsafe way at high speed.